# Check Condition about !TextUtils.isEmpty(..)

Tags: android, firebase

First of all please look at the picture.
 [image]

when i pressed save button apps getting close(if one  of radio button is unchecked ) I write condition kind of like that. this add function perform when the save button get clicked.

```
public void add() {

    String dt = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();
    String s1 = rb.getText().toString().trim();
    String s2 = rb2.getText().toString().trim();
    String s3 = rb3.getText().toString().trim();
    String s4 = rb4.getText().toString().trim();
    String s5 = rb5.getText().toString().trim();
    String s6 = rb6.getText().toString().trim();
    String s7 = rb7.getText().toString().trim(); //here rb-rb7 are radio button


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dt)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s1)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s2)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s3)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s4)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s5)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s6)
            &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s7)) {

        String id = databaseBazars.push().getKey();
        MealE bz = new MealE(dt, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7);
        databaseBazars.child(id).setValue(bz);
        openDialog();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Pleas Fill All the Field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

now my question is, why the else portion is not working though i left the one field empty?? 
for more info if i filled every thing then data inserted in firebase database.

and here is the opendialog function .

```
     public void openDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog1.setTitle("Aleart");
    dialog1.setMessage("Data Updated Successfully");
    dialog1.setNeutralButton(
            "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mDisplayDate.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    niz.clearCheck();
                    rab.clearCheck();
                    sai.clearCheck();
                    sag.clearCheck();
                    nayan.clearCheck();
                    tou.clearCheck();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    dialog1.show();

}
```

what i've done wrong?

Comment: Please provide error log and your xml code of that screen

Comment: First make sure you haven't  messed up with view `ids`.

Comment: evetything is perfect. but the problem is . i left any field empty(without date ) then the if portion of add() is working . why ?

Comment: show your error log

Comment: @meeyan please try with seperate brackets to all conditions inside if i think it may works.hope this helps :)

Comment: please do a example

Comment: Lol your condition checks if radio buttons has text, not if they are checked or not

Comment: so can you do an exmaple ? for solve the problem ? @sel

Answer (score 1):

Please Do Like This

```
 if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(s1) && radioButton1.isChecked())&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s2)&& radioButton2.isChecked()) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(s3)) && radioButton3.isChecked()) {
Log.e("Not Empty","Not Empty"); } else {
Log.e("Empty","Empty");
```

}  }

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it give a error like with this line if i left field empty.  String s1 = rb.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: it's the radio group s1-s7 represents the selected radio button . is there anyway to check item not selected?

Comment: try with this if(radioButton.isChecked())
{
  // is checked    
}

Comment: if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dt)
                &&rb.isChecked()
                &&rb2.isChecked()
                &&rb3.isChecked()
                &&rb4.isChecked()
                &&rb5.isChecked()
                &&rb6.isChecked() 
                &&rb7.isChecked()
                )

Comment: please maintain the seperate brackets i face this issue many times

Comment: i dont think that my answer is wrong why people downvoted the answers?it was working for me.

Comment: people can do just devoting not give the soln. :(

Comment: @Meeyan this solution absolutely fine at my side please check.Answer is updated

Comment: i found the solution. i just use the condition in my button on click listner. which is if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
{
  // no radio buttons are checked
}
else
{
  // one of the radio buttons is checked
}

Comment: my solution is also working please upvote the answer